# How to get alert when you are at bottom of page using HostListener Angular +2

Tags: angular

I'm using this HostListener:

```
@HostListener("window:scroll", [])
    onWindowScroll() {
      const offset = this.window.pageYOffset || this.document.documentElement.scrollTop || this.document.body.scrollTop || 0;
      //How can I display an alert when I'm at bottom of page
    }
```

I used `console.log(this.window.document.body.offsetHeight);` to get the Height, and when I use `console.log(this.window.pageYOffset);` and scroll to end of page, the number doesn't match.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
onWindowScroll() {
  const offset = this.window.pageYOffset || this.document.documentElement.scrollTop || this.document.body.scrollTop || 0;
   if ((this.window.innerHeight + this.document.documentElement.scrollTop) >= this.document.body.offsetHeight) {
        alert("Rock bottom");
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked but I have problem when I put this code in two different component and navigate between them I got message from component 1 that I'm at bottom of component 2.

Comment: that is bc the window and the document variables are shared by all components

Comment: How can I handle this

Comment: On mouse hover, on the whole document, set a global variable, that will change to the name of the component, and then, in the mouse scroll, you can check if it is the right component or not...